# CSS SVG positioning adds unwanted space/scroll bar to page

Tags: html, css, svg, bootstrap-4

I have this basic page layout that consistes of a bootstrap navbar, and an SVG image.

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>
  <header>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
       <div class="container-fluid">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Menu
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something Herer</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another thing here</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search Something" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>

  </header>


<div>
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="image.svg">
</object>
</div>


</body>


</html>
```

Everything fits, and the screen is not scrollable horizontally (which is exactly what I want):

[image]

However, when I position the SVG by adding the following CSS class:

```
.tuner {position: relative; margin-left:50%; transform:translateX(-50%); }
```

And adding the class to the SVG div element:

```
<div class="tuner">
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="image.svg">
</object>
</div>
```

A horizontal scroll bar is added to the page, and when I scroll to the right, additional space exists at the right side of the page:

[image]

My question is, why does this happen, and how can I prevent it?

EDIT: here is the SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="1259.7900390625px" height="430.95001220703125px" viewBox="0.07 -0.05 1259.79 430.95" enable-background="new 0.07 -0.05 1259.79 430.95" xml:space="preserve" >

<rect id="svgEditorBackground" x="0.07" y="-0.05" width="1259.79" height="430" style="fill:none;"/>

<path fill="none" d="M0.11,1h1259.72v429.9H0.11V1z"/>
<rect x="327.7" y="50.34" fill="#382B06" stroke="#000000" width="190.62" height="379.56"/>
<rect x="327.79" y="41.34" fill="#F0EACB" stroke="#000000" width="190.43" height="8"/>
<rect x="327.03" y="142.85" fill="#D1D1D1" width="191.42" height="4.9"/>
<rect x="327.11" y="237.36" fill="#D1D1D1" width="191.42" height="4.9"/>
<rect x="327.18" y="334.88" fill="#D1D1D1" width="191.42" height="4.9"/>
<circle fill="#FAFAD2" stroke="#000000" cx="421.98" cy="287.55" r="12.01"/>

<path id="stop_large" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M589.895,244.124
c0,6.627-5.371,12-12,12h-15c-6.627,0-12-5.373-12-12v-16.024c0-6.627,5.373-12,12-12h15c6.629,0,12,5.373,12,12V244.124z"/>
<rect id="stop_small" pointer-events="none" x="562.395" y="227.975" fill="#050404" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="17" height="17"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Instead of `margin-left`, set `left` - https://jsfiddle.net/7wn2eqrm/

Comment: Thanks, that has stopped the extra space appearing at the side of the page, however, the svg doesn't appear to be in the centre of the page now as I would expect with a 50% setting, it appears way over to the left?

Comment: Use `position: absolute` instead of `position: relative`?

Comment: I've just tried `position: absolute`, and it does move the SVG closer to the centre, but the original issue re-appears, in that additional scrollable space is created at the right hand side of the page, which in turn means the SVG isn't centred properly, because the extra space is taken into account with the 50% settings so the SVG appears over to the right of centre.